# Field audit space

Tags: data-storage, space

Is the field audit data included in the total space of an organization's salesforce account? Is the field Audit storage space free?

Comment: see also http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/field_history_retention.pdf on how to archive field history for ten years (paid feature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to read the [Help & Training](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_monitorresources.htm&siteLang=en_US) information on what counts towards storage. Here's the list at the time of this answer:

- Accounts
- Article types (format: “[Article Type Name]”)
- Article type translations (format: “[Article Type Name] Version”)
- Campaigns
- Campaign Members
- Cases
- Case Teams
- Contacts
- Contracts
- Custom objects
- Email messages
- Events
- Forecast items
- Google docs
- Ideas
- Leads
- Notes
- Opportunities
- Opportunity Splits
- Orders
- Quotes
- Quote Template Rich Text Data
- Solutions
- Tags: Unique tags
- Tasks

Any other type not explicitly mentioned in this list, including field history, do not cost storage.